# Was Once Upon A Time Season 4 pre or post OUAT Wonderland?

Tags: chronology, once-upon-a-time, once-upon-a-time-in-wonderland

So, Once Upon A Time Season 4 introduced Will Scarlet (The Knave) who was the main cast in OUAT Wonderland.

I'm just confused about the timeline here. Did Season 4 happen:

1. before White Rabbit came for Will's help i.e before Wonderland
2. after the whole Wonderland saga ended.

I had no luck at all in finding this bit of info anywhere online.

Comment: The first episode of Once Upon a Time in Wonderland, where the Rabbit comes to Storybrooke for help, took place during the storm caused by the Wraith in the Season 2 premiere of Once Upon a Time.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan in other words, you're implying that OUAT Season 4 happened after wonderland ended? Did I get that right? You might wanna add that as an answer if you have some official sources.